# Does -webkit-font-smoothing only work on Mac browsers, Not windows?

Tags: google-chrome, css, webkit, google-font-api

Does `-webkit-font-smoothing` properties only work on Mac browsers, Not windows? I'm using  a Google font and try to make it smooth in Google Chrome for Windows. I found `-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;` is the solution in Google search but it's not giving any difference on my Google Chrome (Windows)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It only works on mac, not windows because windows has a different font rendering method.

Source: http://christophzillgens.com/en/articles/-webkit-font-smoothing-reloaded

Comment: Does Control Panel > Display Properties > Effects > ClearType for font smoothing have any effect for Windows users in this case?

Comment: @Brad - we cannot tell every user to do this even if it works

Comment: Just wanted to add that this CSS rule is also ineffective on Linux (Gnome desktop, i.e. freetype/pango/gtk+). It's a bit unfortunate, because both Windows and Linux do share the notion of 'cleartyped'/hinted/(non-)antialiased font rendering - in theory this CSS rule should be applicable on these platforms. That said, it appears that 'font-smooth' was dropped from the CSS3-fonts draft, and I suppose that means Chrome/WebKit might drop their implementation too at some point.

Comment: @Brad, tested on Win 7 using Chrome and Safari and different system (Windows) level settings, I see no difference: the browsers use the font smoothing method defined at system level, ignoring `-webkit-font-smoothing` settings.